# How Can I Use A Workflow to Update a Multi-Value Lookup Field?

Tags: sharepoint-designer, sharepoint-online

I'm trying to set values for a multi-value lookup column using a workflow in SharePoint Online (Wave 15). Can anyone tell me how to do it?

I've tried using the update action and setting the value of the field to the string ID;#Value (as specified [here](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/59341/how-to-add-values-from-a-multi-valued-field-from-a-list-using-spds-update-an-it)).  However, its just not working!

Can someone help?  Currently, the workflow just runs with "activity started" forever, there is no error message either :(

Any help would be greatly appreciated!